# where and how to see return values in vscode (or if not possible in gdb) during debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb

The basic interface while debugging a basic c++ file with gdb in `vscode` editor is something like this:
[image]

notice the `line no. 133`  , it contains a function call whose value is not stored in any variable, and it results into a `file path` somewhere in the user's directory. How do we analyze such return values?
My first question is:
Is there a way to watch this return value in `vscode` without having to store the return value in any variable?
Secondly,
If it's not possible to see it in vscode, is there a way to do that in the gdb debugger? Since `vscode` seems to be using the gdb internally, maybe there's a way to setup the `settings.json` using gdb's flags? If anyone knows, please do mention it.